# Working with classes TypeError: unbound method

Tags: python, function, class

```
def isBetween(a, b, c):
    crossproduct = (c[1] - a[1]) * (b[0] - a[0]) - (c[0] - a[0]) * (b[1] - a[1])
    if abs(crossproduct) != 0  : return False

    dotproduct = (c[0] - a[0]) * (b[0] - a[0]) + (c[1] - a[1])*(b[1] - a[1])
    if dotproduct < 0 : return False

    squaredlengthba = (b[0] - a[0])*(b[0] - a[0]) + (b[1] - a[1])*(b[1] - a[1])
    if dotproduct > squaredlengthba: return False
    return True

class HouseLocation(object):

    def __init__(self,street_name,x,y):
      
        self.street_name=street_name
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
    
    def print_address(self):
        print '{}: {},{}'.format(self.street_name,self.x,self.y)
     
class Street(HouseLocation):

     def __init__(self,street_name,map_symbol,street_ends):
        if len(map_symbol)>1:
          raise ValueError('The map_symbol should be only one letter!')
        if map_symbol==str.upper(map_symbol):
           raise ValueError('Make sure that the map_symbol is a small letter!')
         house_locations={}
         global x1,x2,y1,y2
         x1=street_ends[0][0]
         x2=street_ends[1][0]
         y1=street_ends[0][1]
         y2=street_ends[1][1]
    


      def valid_house_to_add(self, house):
         HouseLocation.__init__(house,house.street_name,house.x,house.y)
         ava=isBetween((x1,y1),(x2,y2),(house.x,house.y))
         return ava

      def add_house(self,house):
         HouseLocation.__init__(house,house.street_name,house.x,house.y)
         if Street.valid_house_to_add(house)==True:
              house_locations.update(house,house.x,house.y)
         else:
              raise ValueError("Can not add {} to map").format(house)
```

The code is not yet complete, but so far I have a problem in the last function `add_house`
When I run the following commands in the shell:

> mockingbird = Street("mockingbird lane", "m", ((5,36),(30,36)))
>
> frat_house = HouseLocation("mockingbird lane", 11, 36)
>
> bad_house = HouseLocation("mockingbird lane", 31, 36)
>
> mockingbird.add_house(my_house)
>
> print mockingbird.valid_house_to_add(frat_house)

I get the following error:

> if Street.valid_house_to_add(house)==True:
> TypeError: unbound method valid_house_to_add() must be called with Street instance as first argument (got HouseLocation instance instead)

I am still new to classes, so if anyone can guide me or tell me how to fix the problem that'd be really appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are accessing the method straight on the class:

```
 if Street.valid_house_to_add(house)==True:
```

The expression `Street.valid_house_to_add` retrieves the *unbound* method from the class, meaning it is not associated with an instance.

Access the method on `self` instead, so that it is bound to `self`:

```
 if self.valid_house_to_add(house):
```

Note that you do not need to add `== True`, `if` *already* tests for the truth value.

You also should not be calling `HouseLocation.__init__` from each method. You *probably* want to call that only from `Street.__init__`. In fact, I'd say `Street` should be a *container*, holding `HouseLocation` instances, instead of it being a subclass. Only use subclassing if `Street` is a specialised `HouseLocation`.

Comment: actually it is requested to use HouseLocation for  `valid_house_to_add()` and  `add_house` functions, I will check your answer and come back

Comment: @Enigma: that sounds as if your `Street` object should *contain* `HouseLocation` instances, and not be a subclass of `HouseLocation`.

Comment: what is requested:  `valid_house_to_add()` - this function receives an object of the type  `HouseLocation` as an argument 
*rough translation from another language

Comment: @Enigma: right, so `Street` is not a subclass of `HouseLocation` then. The same way a `list` is not a subclass of, say `int`, you can call `list.append()` to add integers to a list just fine.

Comment: @Enigma: The `Street.add_house()` method just accepts a `HouseLocation` instance and accesses the attributes it defines. That doesn't require `HouseLocation.__init__` to be called.